# mount freebsd slice partition under linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, freebsd

I have under linux:

```
       Device   Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/filename.img      *         63     1007999      503968+  a5  FreeBsd
```

Under above partition i have two slices: ufs filesystem and swap. I don't know, how I can determine mount offset to mount ufs partition.

```
mount -r -t ufs -o loop,offset=32256,ufstype=ufs2 filename.img /test/
```

dmesg output

```
ufs_read_super: bad magic number
```

It's not working.

Comment: The `fdisk` you pasted does not show the partition layout you describe. Try using `parted` or `partx` to display the layout and if that fails, try `testdisk` on the file, since the partition table may be corrupt.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz If you assume that “two slices” was a mistake for “two BSD partitions”, then the text is consistent with the output.

Comment: @Gilles Actually, I was a bit imprecise - I meant that the provided `fdisk` output does not show  the BSD disklabel partitions. I also see now that my later mention of *partition table* was misleading, since here also the *disklabel* is subject to verification.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz The `fdisk` output is clearly Linux's fdisk, showing what in PC/Linux terminology is one partition, and in BSD terminology is one slice. Inside that PC partition a.k.a BSD slice, it is plausible that there are two BSD partitions, root and swap.

Comment: @Gilles That is exactly the problem I was trying to point at - that linux `fdisk` would not see the BSD (disklabel) partitions, so another tool should be used.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's

```
mount -r -o loop,offset=32768,ufstype=ufs2 filename.img /test/
```

If I remember correctly, the first BSD partition starts on a 32kB boundary relative to the whole disk. That's 64 sectors of 512B. Relative to the PC partition, the offset of the BSD partition is 63 sectors, because the PC partition starts at an offset of 1 sector relative to the whole disk: the first sector of the disk contains the partition table.

As suggested by rozcietrzewiacz, you can confirm the offset of the BSD partition with

```
partx -l filename.img
```

There's a [patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/274113/) for the Linux kernel to support automatic access to partitions of loop devices. Debian applies it in their kernels. If you have this patch, then make sure the `loop` driver has a sufficiently large `max_part` parameter (you may need to do `rmmod loop; modprobe max_part=63`). Then the BSD partitions will appear as something like `/dev/loop0p5` and `/dev/loop0p6`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for all hints.

```
# partx -l filename.iso
HDIO_GETGEO: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I added filename mapping which created logical mapping in /dev/mapper directory

```
# kpartx -a filename.iso

# ls -l /dev/mapper/
control  loop0p1
```

the last one check

```
# partx -l /dev/mapper/loop0p1 
1:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
2:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
3:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
4:         0-    49999 (    50000 sectors,     25 MB)
1:   8388671-142078859 (133690189 sectors,  68449 MB)
2:        63-  8388670 (  8388608 sectors,   4294 MB)
```

and the last one with success

```
mount -r -t ufs -o loop,offset=$((8388671*512)),ufstype=ufs2 filename.iso /test/
```

Regards!