# How to mount ufs file system under Debian testing?

Tags: debian, filesystems, ufs

In order to mount my `/dev/sda4`  under `/mnt/ufs_mount` on Debian Testing , i have tried the following commands (it works fine under Debian Jessie):

```
modprobe ufs
mount -r -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sda4 /mnt/ufs_mount
```

and:

```
mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sda4 /mnt/ufs_mount
```

But i get this error:

```
mount: /dev/sda4 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

The output of: `dmesg | tail` :

```
[ 1136.965142] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
[ 1255.758946] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
[ 2098.945757] ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
[ 2098.946045] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

      mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

      >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[ 2098.967212] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
[ 2927.982112] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
```

**Edit**
My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

And `uname -a`:

```
Linux debian 4.6.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1 (2016-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How to mount `ufs` file system under Debian testing?

Comment: Were you able to mount the filesystem in the past?

Comment: @StephenKitt , On debian jessie , i am able to mount the `/dev/sda4` without any problem.

Comment: The message about FS subtype seems indicative. Have you tried using that line for a manual mount attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mount freebsd slice partition under linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23332/mount-freebsd-slice-partition-under-linux), you may need to specify an offset into the partition.

`partx -l` should be able to identify the sector offset of the filesystem, which you'd need to multiply by 512.  You can pass that as a mount option using `-o offset=$((512*sector_offset))` - assuming you're using `bash` or a similar shell.