# How to enable Unix file system support on Linux kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, freebsd, ufs

After switching from Debian stable to Debian testing i have a problem to mount my FreeBSD root partition on my system:
[How to mount ufs file system under Debian testing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308933/how-to-mount-ufs-file-system-under-debian-testing)

I find out what filesystems my Linux kernel supports through this command `cat /proc/filesystems` :

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   hugetlbfs
nodev   devpts
nodev   pstore
nodev   mqueue
    ext3
    ext2
    ext4
nodev   autofs
    btrfs
```

By default The Linux Kernel can’t read/write on `FreeBSD-ufs`  partition.

How to enable Unix file system (`ufs`) support on Linux kernel?

**Update**

the output of:

```
modprobe ufs
mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sda4 /mnt/ufs_mount
```

is:

```
mount: /dev/sda4 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda4,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

The output of `dmesg | tail` :

```
   [ 1136.965142] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
[ 1255.758946] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
[ 2098.945757] ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
[ 2098.946045] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

      mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...

      >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[ 2098.967212] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
[ 2927.982112] perf: interrupt took too long (2504 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
```

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

And `uname -a`:

```
Linux debian 4.6.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1 (2016-07-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a standard debian kernel?

Try `modprobe ufs` as root to load UFS filesystem support.

Comment: I have tried it ,it doesn't work , it work only on debian stable ,thx

Comment: In that case,please update your question with the error message you're getting. Or acknowledge that this is a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308933/how-to-mount-ufs-file-system-under-debian-testing and we'll close it and focus on that one.